# Thunderbird: wrap long URLs when displaying message

Tags: email, thunderbird, url

When I receive an email with a long URL, Icedove (Thunderbird) does not wrap the URL in the message window, but instead shows the long URL in one long line. Additionally, a horizontal scroll bar appears, and I have to scroll to the right to see the end of the URL.

I have set all possible settings to wrap long lines:

```
Preferences -> Advanced -> General -> Config Editor

plain_text.wrap_long_lines   true
view_source.wrap_long_lines  true
mail.wrap_long_lines         true
```

Yet when I send a plaitext email to mysel with following (fictional) URL:

https://www.example.com/order-details?orderId=225-4566698-1254545&j+CEp8SMB57vM8la6tIfkmIvn2WqVw2LjYWH2pK977eldtTDqitIzGWAa87YXrufozCiYnIcRxHiKkWIHar4xReEsFlONvF6I5tbEVJqZLfsYCeMNsNohTSL+aAkwCL29XaNn9aAcWsPtzWLfqRveUHH4hSURo+37CFWtMhwLkzriewF6eAvSy0XjtcWYLCaQHrqDCFMwiUfUHvN0KIlMjvoDIRjgCIAqM4m8aMid3qO2HvRQnNxWswg4KN1m4eIbjo0rZ7EHZPN2jh+frRdThMig2Oshz8D6FJ

this URL is not wrapped in the message view. It is, however, wrapped if I view the message source (using <kbd>ctrl+u</kbd>)

How can I tell Icedove (Thunderbird) to always wrap long lines?

I am using Icedove 24.8.1

Answer (score 0):

Find the `chrome` directory associated with your `icedove` profile, ie:
`$HOME/.icedove/<profile_name>/chrome/`

There should be a file `userContent.css`, (create it, if it does not exist). And add following line:

```
* { word-wrap: break-word; }
```

I have tried this on my machine, and it works with your sample URL